# Visual studio prerequisite Downloading failed with HRESULT=-2146697208

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, clickonce

We have a click once setup programme where we have added  .NET framework and SQL localDB 2014 as prerequisites. We have given the option of "Download prerequisite from the following lication" as shown by the below picture.

[image]

This works fine in all the operating systems except Windows 2012. When we try to install in 2012 it gets the "Downloading failed with HRESULT=-2146697208" error. Following is the full log from install.log

```
The following properties have been set:
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean}
Property: [InstallMode] = SpecificSite {string}
Property: [NTProductType] = 3 {int}
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string}
Property: [VersionNT] = 6.2.0 {version}
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full'
Read string value '4.5.50709'
Setting value '4.5.50709 {string}' for property 'DotNet45Full_TargetVersion'
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)':
Property: [DotNet45Full_TargetVersion] = 4.5.50709 {string}
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'DotNet45Full_TargetVersion' and value '4.5.50709': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_x86_x64.exe' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX45\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe' is 'Bypass'
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: No Install Needed
Running checks for package 'SQL Server 2014 SP1 Express LocalDB', phase BuildList
Looking up path for special folder 'ProgramFilesFolder'
Running check with folder 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\LocalDB\Binn' and file 'sqlservr.exe'
Unable to find directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\LocalDB\Binn'
Not setting value for property 'sqllocaldbVersion'
Looking up path for special folder 'WindowsVolume'
Running check with folder 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\LocalDB\Binn' and file 'sqlservr.exe'
Unable to find directory 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\LocalDB\Binn'
Not setting value for property 'sqllocaldbVersion_x64'
The following properties have been set for package 'SQL Server 2014 SP1 Express LocalDB':
Running checks for command 'SqlLocalDB2014SP1\sqllocaldb_x86.msi'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotExists' on property 'VersionNT': false
Result of running operator 'VersionLessThan' on property 'VersionNT' and value '6.0.1': false
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'AdminUser' and value 'false': false
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'Intel': true
Result of checks for command 'SqlLocalDB2014SP1\sqllocaldb_x86.msi' is 'Bypass'
Running checks for command 'SqlLocalDB2014SP1\sqllocaldb_x64.msi'
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'ProcessorArchitecture' and value 'amd64': false
Skipping ByPassIf because Property 'sqllocaldbVersion' was not defined
Skipping ByPassIf because Property 'sqllocaldbVersion_x64' was not defined
Result of checks for command 'SqlLocalDB2014SP1\sqllocaldb_x64.msi' is 'Install'
'SQL Server 2014 SP1 Express LocalDB' RunCheck result: Install Needed
EULA for components 'SQL Server 2014 SP1 Express LocalDB' was accepted.
Copying files to temporary directory "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD8390.tmp\"
Downloading files to "C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD8390.tmp\"
(5/17/2017 8:47:57 AM) Downloading 'SqlLocalDB2014SP1\sqllocaldb_x64.msi' from 'https://*********/printconnector/prerequisites/SqlLocalDB2014SP1/sqllocaldb_x64.msi' to 'C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\VSD8390.tmp\'
Download completed at 5/17/2017 8:48:04 AM
Downloading failed with HRESULT=-2146697208
```

What would be the reason this only fails on Windows 2012 server and is there anyway to fix this problem? (without giving the option to download prerequisite from the component vender's web site)

Comment: I used to have the same error for some clients and I always suspected it might be something concerning the https: connection in combination with some security settings on the client and the ClickOnce bootstrapper. However, I never tried without ssl because we stopped using ClickOnce anyway. Do you also get this error when you use plain http?

Comment: Yeah, seems like when using plain http instead of https makes the download works again. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the ssl in 2012 since the downloading was a success when using http rather than https.